# How to generate the signed url in the server side using Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I just followed https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol?hl=zh-TW#Signed-URLs to generate signed urls using gsutil and it worked fine.

But my question is "how to generate the signed url in the server side?"

The above cloud storage link mentioned a sample project https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python

Does it fit in the App Engine environment? If so, where should the private key file be located?

Or are there better ways to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python, there is a sample Python application that generates Signed URLs called [storage-signedurls-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python).

Comment: the python sample does work in my local environment, but it has problems when running in GoogleAppEngineLauncher and online. I guess it is because the Launcher and online App Engine don't have "PyCrypto" and "requests". I even tried making "Crypto" inside my project folder, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we made it work:

**Step 1: Get p12 file/certificate**

Download p12 file from https://console.developers.google.com/  
“APIs & auth / Credentials” tab.

**Step 2: Convert p12 file to DER format**

Find a Linux computer open and connect using Terminal
Command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in <filename.p12> -nodes -nocerts > <filename.pem>
# The current Google password for the p12 file is `notasecret`

openssl rsa -in <filename.pem> -inform PEM -out <filename.der> -outform DER
```

**Step 3: Convert DER file to base64 encoded string**

Python console:

```
private_key = open(‘<filename.der>’, 'rb').read()
print private_key.encode('base64')
```

Copy and paste into App engine script.

**Step 4: Enable PyCrypto in AppEngine**

app.yaml must have a line to enable PyCrypto:

```
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
```

**Step 5: Python code to create Signed URL**

```
import Crypto.Hash.SHA256 as SHA256
import Crypto.PublicKey.RSA as RSA
import Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5 as PKCS1_v1_5

der_key = “””<copy-paste-the-base64-converted-key>”””.decode('base64')

bucket = <your cloud storage bucket name (default is same as app id)>
filename = <path + filename>

valid_seconds = 5
expiration = int(time.time() + valid_seconds)

signature_string = 'GET\n\n\n%s\n' % expiration
signature_string += bucket + filename



# Sign the string with the RSA key.
signature = ''
try:
  start_key_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  rsa_key = RSA.importKey(der_key, passphrase='notasecret')
  #objects['rsa_key'] = rsa_key.exportKey('PEM').encode('base64')
  signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
  signature_hash = SHA256.new(signature_string)
  signature_bytes = signer.sign(signature_hash)
  signature = signature_bytes.encode('base64')

  objects['sig'] = signature
except:
  objects['PEM_error'] = traceback.format_exc()

try:
  # Storage
  STORAGE_CLIENT_EMAIL = <Client Email from Credentials console: Service Account Email Address>
  STORAGE_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://storage.googleapis.com'

  # Set the query parameters.
  query_params = {'GoogleAccessId': STORAGE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
                'Expires': str(expiration),
                'Signature': signature}


  # This is the signed URL:
  download_href = STORAGE_API_ENDPOINT + bucket + filename + '?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params)

except:
  pass
```

**Sources**

[How to get the p12 file.](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)

[Signing instructions.](http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs)

[Inspiration for how to sign the url.](http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python)